# Generating and ordering a variable simultaneously

Tags: stata, data-manipulation

I would like to avoid re-ordering the data to place the generated variable in the first column:

```
sysuse auto, clear
gen random = runiform()
order random
```

Is it possible to generate a variable and at the same time order it?

The idea is to be able to directly observe the generated variable when I browse the data in the editor, which is not easy when I have several variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `before()` option:

```
sysuse auto, clear
generate random = runiform(), before(make)
```

You can also further automate this process as follows:

```
unab var : *
gettoken var : var

generate random = runiform(), before(`var')
```

Comment: Thanks, is there something similar with `egen` because the option `before` doesn't seem to work in this case?

Comment: @emeryville Not that I am aware of. It can be done though by writing a program. Ask a new question if you need help with that.

Comment: A side note: the `before()` option is only available since Stata 14.