# Using egen and ordering a variable simultaneously

Tags: stata, data-manipulation

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234995/generating-and-ordering-a-variable-simultaneously), I got an efficient solution to generate a variable and at the same time order it:

```
sysuse auto, clear
generate random = runiform(), before(make)
```

This solution does not seem to work if the `egen` command is used:

```
egen avgprice = mean(price), before(make)
option before() not allowed
r(198);
```

Is it possible to generate a variable and at the same time order it when using `egen`?

Comment: For me, it is not clear why `order` must be avoided, while this command does serve very well and directly (and without any unexpected side-effects) to the desired output.

Comment: I agree with @RomalpaAkzo I avoided using `order` here because the OP said the use of this command is not desirable (for whatever reason which I do not understand). I have now revised my answer to include a solution based on `order` for the sake of illustration.

Comment: I didn't say the use of `order` is not desirable. My point is that I would like to avoid using `order` each time a create variable. Automating this process trough the `egen2` program is great!

Comment: You have to stipulate where the variable goes, either way you do it, so the distance between wanting to avoid it and it being undesirable looks pretty short to me too. On the original question, it is clear from the help or by looking at the code that `egen` does not support this. There is a question of why not,  which is for StataCorp, but many commands generate variables without giving an option for specifying where they go.  As a programmer, you have scope to clone existing commands and add such an option, as @PearlySpencer's answer indicates.

Comment: @emeryville avoiding using `order` and automating the ordering of variables are different things. In my mind at least. I am glad this was resolved to your satisfaction though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `egen` command does not have an option similar to the `before()` option of `generate`.

However, you can accomplish what you want by writing a small program:

```
program define egen2

unab allvars : *
gettoken firstvar : allvars

tempname var
gettoken firstarg 0 : 0, parse("=")

egen `var' `0'
generate `firstarg' = `var', before(`firstvar')

end
```

You could then do the following:

```
sysuse auto, clear

egen2 foo = mean(price)
```

**EDIT:**

The program can be reduced to the following if you do not want to completely avoid `order`:

```
program define egen2

gettoken firstarg 0 : 0, parse("=")
egen `firstarg' `0'
order `firstarg'

end
```